# Omniauth Twitter - No redirect after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth, omniauth

Rails 3.2.11
Omniauth 1.1.3

Omniauth-facebook works but Omniauth-twitter not with the same code.
Setup is minimal like in https://github.com/railscasts/241-simple-omniauth cast.

After `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=u6kWqVH3qY8bg7hMP5dFcHcPGSjKWnZ3YACNP6FsK0`
Twitter redirect me to `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate`. And nothing happens.

I develop with Pow so specify http://xxxyyy.dev/auth/twitter/callback in Settings tab.

Comment: Have the same problem. Did you ever find solution to it?

Comment: Actally I've just found your tip here https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter/issues/47. Creating new Twitter app worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helped me to just use 'Recreate my access token' option in the Details tab of my application.